# Error,when installing a new package in Octave

Tags: octave

I tried to install in Octave these packages:

- `bim`
- `image`

But setup is not finished, because this error:

[image]

Before starting to install packages, I updated the `pkg` itself with the command

```
pkg update
```

After a long update, everything also gives an installation error.
Also reinstalled Octave, the error does not disappear

Comment: That error implies you don't have the package file. Do you have it?

Comment: did you first download those files and are they located in the current working directory?  (do they show up in a `dir` or `ls` command, or appear in the file/folder tree in the upper left section of the GUI?)

Comment: Also, `pkg update` does not update `pkg` itself. It goes through your list of installed pkgs (see `pkg list` and attempts to download and update any that appear out of date.
you should also indicate what version of Octave you're running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use Octave, but based on the [instructions on https://octave.sourceforge.io/](https://octave.sourceforge.io/), you should try

```
pkg install -forge image
pkg install -forge bim
```

to install the Forge [`image`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/image/index.html) and [`bim`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/bim/index.html) packages respectively.